# How can we create the average of a number of samples from different dataframes in Python?

Tags: python, pandas

Good afternoon,

My wife is pregnant with a girl, and her gestational age is about 20 weeks. I've been trying to create a program to take my wife's DNA from Ancestry.com as well as mine, do a number of samples (to prevent outliers) and then sample that toward our daughter (50 from each side) to essentially try to predict which ones our genes go to her.

Here's the code I have. None of this coding at this point returns any errors:

```
M = ("England & Northwestern Europe," * 53) + ("Ireland," * 21) + ("Scotland," * 21) + ("Wales," * 5)
M = M.split(',')
M.pop()
len(M)
```

Output: 100

```
E = ("European Jewish," * 53) + ("Southern Italy," * 31) + ("Levant," * 8) + ("Northern Africa," * 3) + ("Aegean Islands," * 2) + ("Cyprus," * 2) + ("Arabian Peninsula," * 1)
E = E.split(',')
E.pop()
len(E)
```

Output: 100

```
M_df = pd.DataFrame(M)
E_df = pd.DataFrame(E)
```

Now here's the cell I'm having trouble with:

```
def sample(df1, df2, num): #df1 is for one df, df2 is for the second, and num is for the number of samples.
    df1_list = [] 
    df2_list = [] #To keep track of the different columns.
    combined_list = []
    for x in range(1, num+1):
        df1[x] = df1.sample(n=num)
        df2[x] = df1.sample(n=num) #To sample a certain amount of times.
        df1_list.append(df1[x])
        df2_list.append(df2[x]) #Intended to individually number each dataframe as a sample.
        combined_list = df1_list + df2_list #Creating a list of all dataframes together.
        Baby = pd.concat(combined_list) #An averaged list of all data frames together as a data frame. Essentially the intended output.
   
sample(E_df, M_df, 50)
```

The error confused me.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\range.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
    350                 try:
--> 351                     return self._range.index(new_key)
    352                 except ValueError as err:

ValueError: 1 is not in range

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in _set_item(self, key, value)
   3825         try:
-> 3826             loc = self._info_axis.get_loc(key)
   3827         except KeyError:

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\range.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
    352                 except ValueError as err:
--> 353                     raise KeyError(key) from err
    354             raise KeyError(key)

KeyError: 1

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-100-ed9a70bd28b1> in <module>
     11         Baby = pd.concat(combined_list)
     12 
---> 13 sample(E_df, M_df, 50)

<ipython-input-100-ed9a70bd28b1> in sample(df1, df2, num)
      5     for x in range(1, num+1):
      6         df1[x] = df1.sample(n=num)
----> 7         df2[x] = df1.sample(n=num)
      8         df1_list.append(df1[x])
      9         df2_list.append(df2[x])

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in __setitem__(self, key, value)
   3161         else:
   3162             # set column
-> 3163             self._set_item(key, value)
   3164 
   3165     def _setitem_slice(self, key: slice, value):

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in _set_item(self, key, value)
   3241         self._ensure_valid_index(value)
   3242         value = self._sanitize_column(key, value)
-> 3243         NDFrame._set_item(self, key, value)
   3244 
   3245         # check if we are modifying a copy

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in _set_item(self, key, value)
   3827         except KeyError:
   3828             # This item wasn't present, just insert at end
-> 3829             self._mgr.insert(len(self._info_axis), key, value)
   3830             return
   3831 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\managers.py in insert(self, loc, item, value, allow_duplicates)
   1201             value = safe_reshape(value, (1,) + value.shape)
   1202 
-> 1203         block = make_block(values=value, ndim=self.ndim, placement=slice(loc, loc + 1))
   1204 
   1205         for blkno, count in _fast_count_smallints(self.blknos[loc:]):

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\blocks.py in make_block(values, placement, klass, ndim, dtype)
   2740         values = DatetimeArray._simple_new(values, dtype=dtype)
   2741 
-> 2742     return klass(values, ndim=ndim, placement=placement)
   2743 
   2744 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\blocks.py in __init__(self, values, placement, ndim)
    140 
    141         if self._validate_ndim and self.ndim and len(self.mgr_locs) != len(self.values):
--> 142             raise ValueError(
    143                 f"Wrong number of items passed {len(self.values)}, "
    144                 f"placement implies {len(self.mgr_locs)}"

ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 2, placement implies 1
```

Any sort of help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: From a biological point of view you cannot predict which genes for the parent are passed to the child (unless homozygous)

Comment: We aren't taking this all too seriously. It's kind of fun and also an experiment to see how close we are.  I know that there are a number of different limitations and assumptions such as 1) The reliability of the Ancestry tests we took, 2) Different atavisms that we didn't receive but passed through an earlier generation, 3) The different updates that we get that include different labeling at different amounts of each region, etc.

Comment: You have a typo on this line: `df2[x] = df1.sample(n=num)` should be `df2[x] = df2.sample(n=num)`

Comment: Ah, thank you. I corrected that, but it didn't get rid of any of the errors.

Comment: And you should pass a copy of your dataframes as arguments of `sample`: `sample(E_df.copy(), M_df.copy(), 50)` (because DataFrames are mutable objects)

Comment: Will do. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
def sample(df1, df2, num):
    df1_list = [] 
    df2_list = []
    for x in range(1, num+1):
        df1_list.append(df1.sample(n=num))
        df2_list.append(df2.sample(n=num))
    combined_list = df1_list + df2_list
    Baby = pd.concat(combined_list)
    return Baby

# I don't use copy() here because I don't modify E_df or M_df
baby = sample(E_df, M_df, 50)
```

Comment: So I tried this and it didn't raise an error, but the results are two columns with all characters being NaN. This confuses me because yours approached what I'm trying to do but in a different way.

Comment: Hi I have seen that you are very knowledgeable about pandas and data science. I couldn't find way to contact you privately. I am trying to make as many connections as I possibly can and learn from coders as I go along. If it is cool to personally message you about some questions please do let me know